# Flattening nested lists and selecting data in R

Tags: r, list

My data comes in the form of a large number of nested nested lists that looks like this but much larger:

```
data_in <-list(a=list(list(info=c(ID="C.1", treatment="C", color="green"), parameters=c(v=2, d=2), data=mtcars),
                      list(info=c(ID="C.2", treatment="C", color="green"), parameters=c(v=2, d=2), data=mtcars),
                      list(info=c(ID="L.1", treatment="L", color="green"), parameters=c(v=2, d=2), data=mtcars)),
               b=list(list(info=c(ID="C.1", treatment="C", color="green"), parameters=c(v=2, d=2), data=mtcars),
                      list(info=c(ID="C.2", treatment="C", color="green"), parameters=c(v=2, d=2), data=mtcars),
                      list(info=c(ID="L.1", treatment="L", color="green"), parameters=c(v=2, d=2), data=mtcars)),
               c=list(list(info=c(ID="C.1", treatment="C", color="green"), parameters=c(v=2, d=2), data=mtcars),
                      list(info=c(ID="C.2", treatment="C", color="green"), parameters=c(v=2, d=2), data=mtcars),
                      list(info=c(ID="L.1", treatment="L", color="green"), parameters=c(v=2, d=2), data=mtcars)))
```

Is there an elegant solution (using map() or unlist()?) to convert this list of lists to a list of dataframes containing only selected data?

I was looking for a result like this:

```
$a
   ID treatment v d
1 C.1         C 2 2
2 C.2         C 2 2
3 L.1         L 2 2

$b
   ID treatment v d
1 C.1         C 2 2
2 C.2         C 2 2
3 L.1         L 2 2

$c
   ID treatment v d
1 C.1         C 2 2
2 C.2         C 2 2
3 L.1         L 2 2
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want to use only `tidyverse`, then loop to the inner nested layer with `map`, extract the elements of interest ('info', 'parameters'), convert to tibble, remove the 'color' column, bind them in each nested layer (`_dfr`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map(data_in,  ~
   map_dfr(.x, ~ .x[c("info", "parameters")] %>% 
   map_dfc(as_tibble_row)) %>% select(-color))
```

---

Or use a recursive function (`rrapply`) to  extract the elements and convert to `tibble` (as it is a named vector), then bind the datasets in the inner layer, unnest while looping over the outer list with `map`

```
library(rrapply)
library(tidyr)
rrapply(data_in, condition = \(x, .xname) .xname %in%
    c("info", "parameters"), as_tibble_row, how = "prune"  ) %>% 
  map(~ bind_rows(.x) %>%
   unnest(where(is.list)) %>%
   select(-color))
```

-output

```
$a
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  ID    treatment     v     d
  <chr> <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
1 C.1   C             2     2
2 C.2   C             2     2
3 L.1   L             2     2

$b
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  ID    treatment     v     d
  <chr> <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
1 C.1   C             2     2
2 C.2   C             2     2
3 L.1   L             2     2

$c
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  ID    treatment     v     d
  <chr> <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
1 C.1   C             2     2
2 C.2   C             2     2
3 L.1   L             2     2
```

Comment: Great! Does exactly what I need, thank you for the fast help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach where the nested list is first converted to a wide data.frame with `rrapply(..., how = "bind")` and further unnested using `tidyr`. The reason to use `base::split()` instead of  `dplyr::group_split()` is that `base::split()` automatically names the output list of data.frames, whereas `dplyr::group_split()` does not.

```
library(rrapply)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

rrapply(data_in, how = "bind", options = list(namecols = TRUE)) %>%
  unnest_wider(info) %>%
  unnest_wider(parameters) %>%
  select(-matches("L2|color|data")) %>%
  split(f = as.factor(.$L1))

#> $a
#> # A tibble: 3 × 5
#>   L1    ID    treatment     v     d
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 a     C.1   C             2     2
#> 2 a     C.2   C             2     2
#> 3 a     L.1   L             2     2
#> 
#> $b
#> # A tibble: 3 × 5
#>   L1    ID    treatment     v     d
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 b     C.1   C             2     2
#> 2 b     C.2   C             2     2
#> 3 b     L.1   L             2     2
#> 
#> $c
#> # A tibble: 3 × 5
#>   L1    ID    treatment     v     d
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 c     C.1   C             2     2
#> 2 c     C.2   C             2     2
#> 3 c     L.1   L             2     2
```